# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’?

Tags: r

I'm trying to download the package "Seurat" in R, the package is installed and it's now in my list of packages.

```
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (patchwork)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\parnian\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAVgSd8\downloaded_packages’
```

But when I try to call it (library(Seurat)) I get the following error:

```
> library(Seurat)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’:
 object ‘wrap_plots’ is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork'
```

I read the similar questions and manually installed "patchwork":

```
 > install.packages("patchwork")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/parnian/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

R also tells me to install Rtools whhich I have, but when I follow these commands:

```
> writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

but when I want to verify that `make` can be found (`Sys.which("make")`), I get this:

```
> Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""
```

Also my downloaded packages are saved in a location that doesn't even exist in my computer!
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

when you finish

```
> writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

you should restart R.

then `Sys.which("make")` may work.